Why does the quaternion matrix multiplication not result in a unitary matrix?
I've learned that the product of a unit quaternion's complex matrix $Q$ and its conjugate transpose $Q^\dagger$ should be unitary. This implies that the product $Q Q^\dagger = I$ (the identity matrix).
Given that $Q$ and $Q^\dagger$ are $2 \times 2$ complex matrices, let's define them as follows:
$$ Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x + iw & -y + iz \\
y + iz & x - iw
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
Q^\dagger = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x - iw & y - iz \\
y + iz & x + iw
\end{pmatrix}
$$
When we calculate the product $Q Q^\dagger$, we get:
$$
QQ^\dagger = 
\begin{pmatrix}
(x + iw)(x - iw) + (y - iz)(y + iz) & (x + iw)(y - iz) + (y - iz)(x + iw) \\
(y + iz)(x - iw) + (x - iw)(y + iz) & (y + iz)(y - iz) + (x - iw)(x + iw)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The specific results of the multiplication are as follows:

Top-left element: $1$
Top-right element: $(x + iw)(y - iz) + (y - iz)(x + iw) \neq 0$
Bottom-left element: $(y + iz)(x - iw) + (x - iw)(y + iz) \neq 0$
Bottom-right element: $1$

From this calculation, we see that the off-diagonal elements (top-right and bottom-left) are not zero.
My question: How can this matrix still be considered unitary when the off-diagonal elements do not equal zero? Isn't this a contradiction?

In MathJax, \[...\] does not work. Use $$...$$ instead.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. It's easier to do this calculation without mistakes if you write $Q$ in terms of these.

There are small mistakes on the off-diagonal entries of $Q^\dagger$. It should be $$Q^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix}
x - iw & y - iz \\
-y - iz & x + iw
\end{pmatrix}$$ since $\dagger$ switches the entries and makes $i$ into $-i$. There is no sign change for the $y$ since $y$ is real. This should fix the bottom-right entry of $QQ^\dagger$. For the top-right entry $QQ^\dagger$, the second $y - iz$ should be $-y + iz$ since it is from the top-right entry of $Q$. This should make it zero.

Your answer was a great help to me. I'm glad that recalculating the conjugate transpose helped and that the other terms turned out to be zero.
